# extjs google maps v3 not working

Tags: google-maps-api-3, extjs4

hello i'm trying to add google maps for my window i'm using mvc i didn't see any example based on mvc here is my code

```
Ext.define('UserApp.view.uiTypes.GoogleMaps',{
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    width:800,
    height:250,
    bodyPadding: 5,
    title:'Google Maps',
    requires: ['Ext.ux.GMapPanel'],
    items:[

        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            label: 'test'
        },
        {
            xtype:'textfield',
            label:'hellworld'
        },
        {
             xtype: 'gmappanel',
            region: 'center',
            id:  'mygooglemap',
            zoomLevel: 3,
            gmapType: 'map',
            mapConfOpts:['enableScrollWheelZoom','enableDoubleClickZoom','enableDragging'],
            mapControls: ['GSmallMapControl','GMapTypeControl','NonExistantControl'],   
            setCenter: {
                'lat': 37.4419,
                'lng': -122.1419,
                marker:{ title: 'Palo Alto'}
            }
        }

    ],
});
```

error in console

Uncaught Error: Invalid value for property : function (){var a=this,b;if(a.isVisible()){b=a.el.getAlignToXY(a.container,"c-c");a.setPagePosition(b)}else{a.needsCenter=true}return a}

Comment: You must edit your question. I don't use extjs but I don't think even someone that does will be of assistance. Is there an error on your console log? Are you talking about sencha? Because I think they have plenty of examples.

Comment: done i hope someone can help me in this

Comment: Examples might be found here: https://github.com/VinylFox/ExtJS.ux.GMapPanel/ I'm guessing the component your are using is based on the one VinylFox created?

Comment: nope i'm trying to use this one http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.ux.GMapPanel

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using GMapPanel3....
You can try to do something like this :

```
var smallGoogleMap = {
                xtype: 'gmappanel',
                id :'gSmallSiteMap',
                width:'100%',
                height:200,
                zoomLevel:10,
                gmapType: 'map',
                mapConfOpts: ['enableScrollWheelZoom','enableDoubleClickZoom','enableDragging'],
                mapControls: ['GSmallMapControl','GMapTypeControl','NonExistantControl'],
                setCenter: {
                    lat: 42.339641,
                    lng: -71.094224,
                  marker: { 
                      title: 'Boston Museum of Fine Arts',
                      listeners: {
                          click: function(e) {
                              Ext.Msg.alert('It\'s fine', 'and it\'s art.');
                          }
                      }
                    }
                }
    }
Ext.getCmp('some div or window').add(smallGoogleMap);
```

OR : You can simply replace the part inside `items[]` and put the variable `smallGoogleMap`.

Let me know if this doesn't work!

Comment: what if i need to render google maps without div just inside panel it's working but if i opend other window it's displayed with black background in window

Comment: You need to provide a `div` / `Ext Component - can be window / panel,etc` in order to render the map.
Also from what I understand, you are trying to open one more google map in another window? So in that case, you'll need to provide a new Ext Component with a `different ID`..

Comment: umm sounds good nope i don't open any other google maps i think the problem is just i need to set google maps in window that's all thanks man :) for your help

Comment: No problem, if you could provide some code, it would be easier for me to guide you through!

Comment: here is my full code for google maps http://pastebin.com/6MV3envX however if i open other window else this one it's give me black div in my screen i don't use html just extjs also this code for panel and render inside popup window

Comment: So you mean, after you click on the button 1st time, to show the map, it shows properly.. but the next time you click on the same button, you see a black div? Just to clear up the question.. If this is your issue I might know the answer.. do tell me if this is not what your problem is!

Comment: yea this is the problem exactly when i'm trying to open any other window else the popup window opened for google maps

Comment: Well, I think the map is loaded already for that div.. which you are getting by id I believe.. Just double check if you are `not` creating the `div` with the same `ID` again.. 
Are you still getting the error which you mentioned in the question? Also, providing some code would be helpful to understand and get to the root cause!